# MacBook Pro: "Zero bytes left on iCloud" even after upgrading storage plan

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, finder

I am facing an issue with my iCloud Drive. My MacBook Pro does not want to sync up the files anymore which are on my machine.

My iCloud storage was full so I upgraded my storage plan.
I can see the storage available when checking iCloud in system preferences.

See screenshot below
[image: storage screenshot]

When I open the finder and navigate to iCloud Drive. The following message appears in the bottom of the finder window.
`1 of 20 selected, Zero bytes available on iCloud`.

These are the things I tried.

```bsh
  killall bird
  cd ~/Library/Application\ Support
  mv CloudDocs/ OldCloudDocs
```

I killed bird via the activity monitor.
I updated macOS `currently on version: 10.15.2 (19C57)`.
I went to system preferences->iCloud-> iCloud Drive->options and toggled the Desktop & Document folders option.

All with no result..

Comment: It might take some time to adopt the changes. How long did you wait since you upgraded your plan?

Comment: A couple of hours. But the change is visible on the screenshot I showed you right.. so why should it still take time?

Comment: Thats weird indeed. Kinda basic, but have you done a restart and turned off all connectivity?

Comment: I restarted the machine 3 times, one time just to check of the settings applied after restart, another time right after the commands I did in the terminal and the last time for the update..

Comment: Have you logged out of iCloud and back in again? Sometimes a reboot doesn't do it.

Comment: No I haven't done that. Maybe a good option for people who face a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

After restarting for a couple of more times, the issue resolved for me.